# Using offsetof to perform pointer arithmetic example

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was trying to learn about acessing struct memebers by using the `offsetof()` macro and I ran into this example [How can I access structure fields by name at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515707/how-can-i-access-structure-fields-by-name-at-run-time) 
This line:

```
//Set the value of 'a' using pointer arithmetic
*(int *)((char *)structp + offsetf) = 5;
```

gives me trouble.
Why is the pointer being cast to a `char *` and then back to an `int *`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is fine to reference another question, but it is important to make your question comprehensible without us needing to go and look.  We need to see more of the code fragment to understand what's going on.  We can guess; we shouldn't have to.  Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) and do so.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the struct pointer has to be cast to "byte pointer" type, since `offsetf` most likely contains the *byte-offset* of the desired struct field. Because of this cast, pointer arithmetic in `(char *)structp + offsetf` subexpression is performed in terms of `char` objects (in terms of bytes), exactly as we want it.

Secondly, the above subexpression gives us a pointer of type `char *` that points to the desired data field. But in reality that data field apparently has type `int`. So, in order to gain access to that data field we have to cast our `char *` pointer to the proper `int *` type. After that we can perform read (or write) access to that data field by using the unary `*` operator.

In your case value `5` is written into an `int` data field located at byte-offset `offsetf` inside an object pointed by `structp`.

Comment: @AnT: Apologies - misread.  You're correct.  I'll delete this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Because in order: you derreference `*` something casted into `int*` so you can acess the data and set it to `5`.

The cast into char * is because casting `char *` to `int *` is easy due to the fact that every `char` has an integer value.